# Running a script post successful build in jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am trying to run a bash script after a successful build in jenkins.

```
stages {
  stage("test") {
    steps {
      ...
    }
    post {
      success {
        steps {
          sh "./myscript"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting an error saying that method "steps" does not exist. How can I run a script after a successful build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the ”steps” inside the ”success” block. call the script directly inside the ”success” block.

according to the docs which is quite confusing, the ”success” is a container for steps (so no need to add another nested ”steps” ):

> https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post

```
stages {
  stage("test") {
    steps {
      ...
    }
    post {
      success {
        sh "./myscript"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much

Comment: if you are satisfied, please accept the answer. thanks.